# Create a networked virtual HDD/file system

Tags: java, c++, filesystems, driver

How would i go about creating a networked virtual HDD/file system? By that I mean, once I install the application a new drive (possibly need to create a driver?) shows up on windows (Mac or Linux?) and when you open the drive it shows you files stored on a server somewhere that can be copied to the local file system or add new files the way you usually would a normal drive...

Any existing libraries that do this? If not, any literature you can point me to that would set me off in the right direction?

Comment: this question is way, way, way too broad. if you're looking for how to get started on network/distributed file systems, look at the existing literature for the existing systems (NFS, SMB/CIFS, OCFS, GFS, ...). If you're looking for filesystem driver code, research the same topics with a given OS in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to write a filesystem driver.  On Linux you can use [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) if you don't want to do kernel programming, at the cost of performance.  I don't know about options for Windows or Mac OS.

You've tagged this question with the Java tag, but you're more likely to have to use C or C++.  If your driver will run in a userspace process (such as via FUSE), I guess you could load a JVM and write stub C functions that just proxy to Java methods, but that's probably more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: thanks, fuse has lead me to Dokan (windows) and others as well...

Answer (score 1):

On Windows this can be done using one of our products - [SolFS OS Edition](http://www.eldos.com/solfs/drv-benefits.php) or [Callback File System](http://www.eldos.com/cbfs/). Both have JNI interface to their functions. You can check the differences between two products in the [comparison chart](http://www.eldos.com/suppl/vs_compare.php).

*SolFS OS Edition* is available also for MacOS X and can be released for Linux (we have the code, but didn't release the product).

On Linux the analog of *CBFS* is FUSE, on MacOS it's MacFUSE.