# Java WebDAV client as a virtual drive in Windows

Tags: java, webdav, drive

I would like to have a WebDAV client in Windows that shows a WebDAV source as a virtual drive. I have been using Netdrive2 for a while, but I'd rather either write my own Java implementation or use an existing open source product.

I've noticed many Java based WebDAV clients, but they do not seem to act as a Windows drive. Do they exist, or is it even possible to create a Java program that creates a virtual drive, pointing to some Java collection of File elements? Or even better, a collection of custom elements that represent the resources provided by the Java WebDAV client?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm almost sure this won't be possible without some native Windows code (e.g. C/C++). Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767705/create-a-networked-virtual-hdd-file-system), though it might not be really helpful in your case.

Comment: Thanks I noticed that one. I go with @Eugene 's answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Explorer has built-in WebDAV support. If you need a virtual drive, you need a library that will let you create a virtual disk. WebDAVSystem used to offer such (but this is a commercial product) but I don't see that library on their site anymore. They used our Callback File System to create a virtual drive.

Callback File System itself includes WebDAVDisk sample for C# (not for Java API at the moment). That sample is based on our SecureBlackbox components for WebDAV connectivity and also uses parts of the code from our SFTP Net Drive freeware application. We have plans to write the same sample in all other supported APIs (Java, Delphi, C++).

Comment: I just had no idea that Windows has built-in WebDAV support. Because I was using a commercial product that supports WebDAV which I was not satisfied about, I assumed I would have to create something myself. The Windows WebDAV information works for me. Although it would have been a challenge to build it :-). Thanks!

Comment: Native Windows implementation is limited to 4 GB file size, though.