# Using Java to create a Virtual partition in hard drive

Tags: java

I am trying to use Java to create a Virtual partition in hard drive. Is it possible to  use standard java I/O to do it (write binary)? Or I have to write a low level drivers to do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767705/create-a-networked-virtual-hdd-file-system refer this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a networked virtual HDD/file system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767705/create-a-networked-virtual-hdd-file-system)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guese would be to use a simple `ProccesBuilder` command. Though that is platform dependend.

on windows you can create a drive which points to an existing folder in your current harddrive using:

```
subst [drive_letter]: [file_folder]

//example
subst E: C\path\to\my own folder
```

To delete that drive, you can simply do:

```
subst [drive_letter]: /D

//example
subst E: /D
```

Im not that experianced with [lunix](https://www.tylerburton.ca/2014/06/create-a-virtual-hard-drive-volume-within-a-file-in-linux/) and/or [Mac](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2097401) systems, though you can find plenty forums/tutorials online (including any other OS of course).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but if my Virtual partition want to set a size limit, is it possible to do this with your "ProccesBuilder" command in java?

Comment: If you really need a memory limited drive you need to use a thirdparty tool/API Im afraid, since it cannot be done by a simple command from what I know.